# Index (-1, 5) out of bounds for length 5?

Tags: java, arrays, maze

I'm new to Java coding so please be kind. I am trying to create a maze game using a 2D array in the console. Everything prints fine, until I go to make a move. I have it set so you select a number in order to move in that direction. Each time I try to move, I will get the error "index (-1 or 5, depending on the move) out of bounds for length 5". If someone could take a look at my code and give me some feedback that would be greatly appreciated.

```java
public class trest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //scans user input
        int rowsTotal = 5;
        int columnsTotal = 5;
        int vxTemp = 0;
        int vyTemp = 0;
        
        //creates variables (vx= variable x) (TEMP = TEMP PLAYER POS.)
        //Create short display showing "logo": who made it and what its purpose is for.
        //maybe simple sys out "Welcome to maze game for mentally challenged, by Jack Paster and co."
        String[][] mazeStructure = {
                {"P", ".", "!", "!", "."},
                {".", ".!", ".", ".", "."},
                {"", ".", ".", "!", "."},
                {"!", "!", ".", "T", "."},
                {"!", ".", "!", "!", "."},
        };
        boolean won = false;
        while (won == false) {
            for (int a = 0; a < rowsTotal; a++) {
                for (int b = 0; b < columnsTotal; b++) {
                    System.out.print(mazeStructure[a][b]);
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }//prints the maze
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
            System.out.println("Please select one of the following:");
            System.out.println("Press 1 to move up.");
            System.out.println("Press 2 to move down.");
            System.out.println("Press 3 to move left.");
            System.out.println("Press 4 to move right.");
            System.out.println("Press 0 to stop playing the game.");
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            //Gives options for movement
            //scans for input input
            int a = 0;
            if (choice == 1 && a >= 0 && a < columnsTotal) {
                //if choice is 1, do this
                for (int x = 0; x < rowsTotal; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < columnsTotal; y++) {
                        if (mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp - 1].equals("!") == false && mazeStructure[x][y].equals(mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp])) {
                            //if mazeStructure is valid (doesnt = !, in parameters)
                            mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = ".";
                            mazeStructure[x][y - 1] = "P";
                            mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = mazeStructure[x][y - 1];
                            //change old temp to ., move down. temp is now y-1. TEMP = PLAYER Pos.
                        } else if (mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp - 1] == "!") {
                            //if player tries to move into !, dont allow.
                            System.out.println("Move isn't allowed.");
                        } else {
                            continue;
                        }//continue
                    }
                }
            } else if (choice == 2 && a >= 0 && a < columnsTotal) {
                //if choice is 2, do this
                for (int x = 0; x < rowsTotal; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < columnsTotal; y++) {
                        if (mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp + 1].equals("!") == false && mazeStructure[x][y].equals(mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp])) {
                            //if mazeStructure is valid (doesnt = !, in parameters)
                            mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = ".";
                            mazeStructure[x][y + 1] = "P";
                            mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = mazeStructure[x][y + 1];
                            //change old temp to ., move up. temp is now y+1. TEMP = PLAYER Pos.
                        } else if (mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp + 1] == "!") {
                            //if player tries to move into !, dont allow.
                            System.out.println("Move isn't allowed.");
                        } else {
                            continue;
                        }//continue
                    }
                }
            } else if (choice == 3 && a >= 0 && a < columnsTotal) {
                //if choice is 3, do this
                for (int x = 0; x < rowsTotal; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < columnsTotal; y++) {
                        if (mazeStructure[vxTemp - 1][vyTemp].equals("!") == false && mazeStructure[x][y].equals(mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp])) {
                            //if mazeStructure is valid (doesnt = !, in parameters)
                            mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = ".";
                            mazeStructure[x - 1][y] = "P";
                            mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = mazeStructure[x - 1][y];
                            //change old temp to ., move left. temp is now x-1. TEMP = PLAYER Pos.
                        } else if (mazeStructure[vxTemp - 1][vyTemp] == "!") {
                            System.out.println("Move isn't allowed.");
                            //if player tries to move into !, dont allow.
                        } else {
                            continue;
                        }//continue
                    }
                }
            } else if (choice == 4 && a >= 0 && a < columnsTotal) {
                for (int x = 0; x < rowsTotal; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < columnsTotal; y++) {
                        if (mazeStructure[x][y].equals(mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp]) && mazeStructure[vxTemp + 1][vyTemp].equals("!") == false) {
                            //if mazeStructure is valid (doesnt = !, in parameters)
                            mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = ".";
                            mazeStructure[x + 1][y] = "P";
                            mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = mazeStructure[x + 1][y];
                            //change old temp to ., move left. temp is now x+1. TEMP = PLAYER Pos.
                        } else if (mazeStructure[vxTemp + 1][vyTemp] == "!") {
                            System.out.println("Move isn't allowed.");
                        } else {
                            continue;
                        }//continues
                    }
                }
            } else if (choice == 0) {
                System.exit(0);
                //if choice is 0, quit the game.
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You Won! Congratulations!");
        input.close();
        //quit game.
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help if you show the full stack trace of the exception, indicating what line it occurs on.

Comment: I struggle to understand why you need those loops when you make a move. I think all you want to do is: (a) check that your current position is within the limits fo a valid move (e.g. don't move up when you are in the first row) and (if test (a) is successful) b) check that the target spot is not a wall. When both tests are successful, put a '.' on your old position, change your position and put a 'P' to the new position. All that does not need loops over x and y.

Comment: Please, in the future, if you have a problem on line x, just copy and paste the snippet which is related to that line.. instead of pasting an entire file. We only need [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Every time in your code, when you using `x-1`, `x+1`, `y-1` etc., in loop, you try to get index outside the array. You have to protect your code against it.

Comment: I added a protection... now Im unsure how to fix it. I will move "down" but nothing will change. It displays the same maze again. I hit "right" and same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The program contains a 5x5 matrix and you are traversing through it using loops.
Its quite obvious that you will hit out of bounds since you are using relative index with +1.
Eg.

```
for (int x = 0; x < rowsTotal; x++){
    for (int y = 0; y < columnsTotal; y++){
        if (mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp+1].equals("!") == false && mazeStructure[x][y].equals(mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp])){
                    //if mazeStructure is valid (doesnt = !, in parameters)
                    mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = ".";
                    mazeStructure[x][y+1] = "P"; **<<--- Look here**
                    mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp] = mazeStructure[x][y+1];
                  //change old temp to ., move up. temp is now y+1. TEMP = PLAYER Pos.
        }else if (mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp+1] == "!"){
                        //if player tries to move into !, dont allow.
                    System.out.println("Move isn't allowed.");
        }else {
        continue;}//continue

           }
         }
```

The code  `mazeStructure[x][y+1] = "P";` will hit an out of bound exception when y is at value 4, as your loop is expected to loop till `columnsTotal` which is 5.

There are multiple lines in this code where you are doing this with x and y. Please debug to see the cases.

Answer (score 1):

The Exception gets thrown because you try to access an array element that does not exist.

If you try to move up it occurs because you initialize `vyTemp` with 0 and try to access `mazeStructure[vxTemp][vyTemp - 1]` which is -1 which is not supported by java.
When you try to move to the left something similar happens but with `vxTemp` instead of `vyTemp`.

For that, I would suggest adding a check if you are out of bounds:

```
if (vyTemp - 1 >= 0)
{
    // do it
}
```

If you try to move down it occurs on line 89 `mazeStructure[x][y + 1] = "P";` because you iterate over your whole 2D array which means y is 4 at some point so y + 1 is out of bounds.
When you try to move to the right the same happens but with `x` instead of `y`.

I am not quite sure why you are iterating over the whole array but an out-of-bounds check would work for that as well I guess.